# Return Static Data from Axios

Tags: json, react-native, axios

Currently, I have Axios-based functions such as this:

```
someFunction(payload: any) {
    let axiosPromise = this.service.post({
      url: this.path,
      data: payload,
      headers: this.baseHeader
    });

    return(axiosPromise);
}
```

and life is good.  However, if the this.path URL is `local`, I would like to return canned data.  In this fashion, I can do development in a disconnected state.  How would I attach a canned JSON response to the Promise in the case of a `local`-based URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like [axios-mock-adapter](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter)

For example you could check if you're in a DEV environment and do something like this

```
mock.onGet(this.path, { data: payload }).reply(200, {
  ...yourFakeDataObject
});
```

This would mock all the GET requests to your path.